# Lowercase the first word

Tags: vb.net, cpu-word, lowercase

Does anybody know how to lowercase the first word for each line in a textbox?

Not the first letter, the first word.

I tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
For Each iz As String In txtCode.Text.Substring(0, txtCode.Text.IndexOf(" "))
     iz = LCase(iz)
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are running the loop **only** on each character of the **first** word in the whole TextBox text.

This code is looping over each line and takes the first word:

```
For Each line As String In txtCode.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    line = line.Trim().ToLower()

    If line.IndexOf(" ") > 0 Then
        line = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(" ")).Trim()
    End If

    // do something with 'line' here
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `Substring`, it is making a copy of that portion of the string and returning it as a new string object.  So, even if you were successfully changing the value of that returned sub-string, it still would not change the original string in the `Text` property.

However, strings in .NET are immutable reference-types, so when you set `iz = ...` all you are doing is re-assigning the `iz` variable to point to yet another new string object.  When you set `iz`, you aren't even touching the value of that copied sub-string to which it previously pointed.

In order to change the value of the text box, you must actually assign a new string value to its `Text` property, like this:

```
txtCode.Text = "the new value"
```

Since that is the case, I would recommend building a new string, using a `StringBuilder` object, and then, once the modified string is complete, then set the text box's `Text` property to that new string, for instance:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
For Each line As String In txtCode.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    ' Fix case and append line to builder
Next
txtCode.Text = builder.ToString()
```

Answer (score 3):

The solutions here are interesting but they are ignoring a fundamental tool of .NET: **regular expressions**. The solution can be written *in one expression*:

```
Dim result = Regex.Replace(txtCode.Text, "^\w+",
    Function (match) match.Value.ToLower(), RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

(This requires the import `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.)

This solution is likely more efficient than all the other solutions here (It’s *definitely* more efficient than most), and it’s less code, thus less chance of a bug and easier to understand and to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each of the lines of the textbox, splitting all of the words in the line, making sure to .ToLower() the first word:

```
    Dim strResults As String = String.Empty

    For Each strLine As String In IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Test\StackFlow.txt").Split(ControlChars.NewLine)

        Dim lstWords As List(Of String) = strLine.Split(" ").ToList()

        If Not lstWords Is Nothing Then

            strResults += lstWords(0).ToLower()

            If lstWords.Count > 1 Then

                For intCursor As Integer = 1 To (lstWords.Count - 1)

                    strResults += " " & lstWords(intCursor)

                Next

            End If

        End If

    Next
```

Answer (score -2):

I used your ideas guys and i made it up to it like this:

```
For Each line As String In txtCode.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)

            Dim abc() As String = line.Split(" ")
            txtCode.Text = txtCode.Text.Replace(abc(0), LCase(abc(0)))

Next
```

It works like this. Thank you all.

Comment: That will only keep the first word of the last line.

Comment: Also, you should use `abc(0).ToLower()` rather than the old VB6-style `LCase` function.

Comment: This code does something **completely** different from what you wanted (it replaces *all* occurrences of a given word, everywhere it appears in the text), in addition to having several other flaws (it’s inefficient, it’s using deprecated methods as Steven pointed out in his comment) and it’s unnecessarily complex.

Comment: PRINT < TEST >     ||goes to||     print < TEST >      || that's what i wanted and it works like this..